# PyWin32 get network information/statistics

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

I am trying to get `Network Statistics` for my `Windows 7` system using `PyWin32`.

The steps I followed:

> 1) Run `COM MakePy utility` and than select `network list manager 1.0
>   type library` under type library.
>
> 2) Above process generated this [python file](http://pastebin.com/y7hQGQdR).

Now the problem I am facing is after the above two steps what should be my `next step`. I tried a couple of things like:

I copied the `CLSID = IID('{DCB00000-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B}')` line from the above generated python file and used it like

```
>>> import win32com
>>> obj = win32com.client.gencache.GetClassForCLSID("{DCB00000-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B}")
>>> obj.GetConnectivity()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method GetConnectivity() must be called with INetworkListManager instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

When I do `obj.method()` it show a list of all available method.

[image]

So, now I have no idea what to do or how to proceed and what is the general process of using `Type library` with pywin32.

The above task is just a part of learning process on how to use `PyWin32`,`COM MakePy utility`.

Is this even achievable using pywin32.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use win32com.client.Dispatch to actually create the object.
Also, the class you start with is the CoClass, in this case

```
class NetworkListManager(CoClassBaseClass): # A CoClass
```

is the one you want.

```
win32com.client.Dispatch('{DCB00C01-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B}')
```

works here.

Many of these Dispatch classes have a human readable dotted name as an alias, although
this particular one doesn't seem to.

Comment: Thanks for your input. So I was able to create the object using your suggestion. But the problem now I am facing is how to use other classes like `INetwork, INetWorkConnection` and their methods using pywin32.