# PyWin32 using MakePy utility and win32com to get Network Statistics

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

This question is in continuation to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9970054/776084).

I am trying to get `Network Statistics` for my `Windows 7` system using `PyWin32`.

The steps I followed:

> 1) Run `COM MakePy utility` and than select `network list manager 1.0
>   type library` under type library.
>
> 2) Above process generated this [python file](http://pastebin.com/y7hQGQdR).

Next I created the object of  class `NetworkListManager(CoClassBaseClass)` using

```
import win32com.client as wc
obj = wc.Dispatch("{DCB00C01-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B}")
```

Now I am trying to access the methods provided by the above created object `obj`.

`help(obj)` gave me

**GetNetwork(self, gdNetworkId= `<PyOleEmpty object>`)**

```
Get a network given a Network ID.
```

**IsConnected**

```
Returns whether connected to internet or not

//Other methods removed
```

So, now when I use

```
>>> obj.IsConnected
True
```

It works fine.

Now the problem I am facing is how to use `GetNetowrk` method because when I try to use it

```
>>> obj.GetNetwork()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
      ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(2, LCID, 1, (9, 0), ((36, 1),),gdNetworkId
com_error: (-2147024809, 'The parameter is incorrect.', None, None)
```

I also tried creating `PyOleEmpty object` by using `pythoncom.Empty` and passed it as a paremeter but no luck.

I understand `GetNetwork` require `NetworkID` as a parameter but the method `GetNetworkId` is defined in [INetwork](http://pastebin.com/qRWWjuD4) class.

So my question is how to use classes defined in the python file created using `MakePy utility` which are not `CoClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the way to get to the Network objects is to enumerate them using GetNetworks:

```
networks=obj.GetNetworks(win32com.client.constants.NLM_ENUM_NETWORK_CONNECTED)
for network in networks:
    print (network.GetName(), network.GetDescription())
```

Using the network ids will be problematic.  They're defined as raw structs, so they will need to be passed using Records.  Pywin32's support for the IRecordInfo interface is still somewhat weak.

Comment: Nice it worked but I was wondering how did you figured it out.